# ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION query returning all rows ranked as 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am having issues with a query, I want it to rank the result based on the time the last change was recorded.

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ph.pricingHistoryId ORDER BY ph.changeRecorded DESC),
  ph.*
FROM
  PriceHistory ph
```

It returns all 1 for the ranking.

Comment: Is ph.pricingHistoryId unique? The row number is applied to each partition and reset for the next partition.

Comment: Yes, it is unique - the primary key for the table

Comment: Then you need to partition over the group you want numbered. If the entire set, remove the entire "PARTITION BY ph.pricingHistoryId" part.

Comment: @Akhil thanks - must have missed something in the examples I was looking at. Put it as an answer and I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: you mean Unique Key? if its the primary key all your partitions would return result as 1

Comment: @Sam, i have updated it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `pricingHistoryId` is the Primary Key, Partitioning by it always returns the rank as 1 because there cannot be repetitive primary keys!

Answer (score 1):

The row number is applied to each partition and reset for the next partition. You need to "partition over" the group you want numbered. If you want one sequence over the entire result set, remove the "PARTITION BY ph.pricingHistoryId" entirely and just keep the "ORDER BY" part.